# Issue reading String

Tags: android

I have an issue with my basic addition program everything works such as typing the value and testing if its not wrong but an issue occurs when i open my program and leave the TextView blank and press button check , the program terminates.
Ive tried convert String =""; to an integer but then my program does not start.
I belive it only compares integers and not String but im unsure how to overcome it
Any help would be appreciated.

```
int one=1, two=2;
ans = one + two;
TextView = Value;
TextView = i;

Button one,check;

i = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display);
Value = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer);

one= (Button) findViewById(R.id.one);
one.setOnClickListener(this);

check= (Button) findViewById(R.id.check);
check.setOnClickListener(this);


        public void onClick(View v) {

        switch(v.getId()){  


        case R.id.one:
            ans.append("1");
            break;

        case R.id.check:

        if (answer ==(Integer.parseInt(Value.getText().toString())))
            {

             display.setText(one+"+"+two);
             ans.setText("");

            }

           else
               {
           i.setText("Invalid");
               }

            break;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
Integer.parseInt(Value.getText().toString())
```

From the docs:

> Throws: "NumberFormatException - if the string does not contain a
>   parsable integer."

So you should probably wrap that line in a try/catch (catch NumberFormatException), and tell the user that their input is invalid if the exception was thrown. Further more set the input type of the edit text to 'number'.

Answer (score 0):

You need to validate your input. You have to make sure that whatever the user enters into the text box is valid and not garbage. If the user enters garbage then use `try catch` to gently handle the exception and let the user know via a toast message that the input is not valid.

Hope you understand this simple aspect of programming.

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of issues with your code:
Define int tempVal =0;

```
1) TextView = Value; is not correct I guess. TextView and EditText are two different things.

2) Value = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer);
I thik it should be 
EditText txtVal= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.answer);
3) 
String txtValStr= txtVal.getText();

4) if (txtValStr != null || !"".equals(txtValStr))
{
 tempVal = new Integer(txtValStr).intValue();
}


inside case:

if(tempVal == answer)
{
....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use an if statement

```
String s = Value.getText().toString();
if (s != null && !s.matches("")){
    // Do your code
} else {
    // use a toast to prompt them to enter something
}
```

That checks o see if the string is null, or empty, and if it's not, you can parse it.